# Sum of reciprocals of triangle numbers with alternating sign

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to determine the sum $\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{15}-\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{28}-\frac{1}{36}+...$, i.e. the reciprocal triangle numbers beginning at $+\frac{1}{6}$ and alternating in sign thereafter. Is there a way I can group terms in order to produce a telescoping series? If not, what other method of summation could I try?

Comment: This is basically $\log 2$.  Just start with the usual expansion of that, and adapt it.

Comment: Well, I guess it's a bit harder than that...see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5En*2%2F%28n%28n%2B1%29%29%2C+%7Bn+%2C+1%2C+infinity%7D%5D).  Note that I started with $n=1$ where you start with $n=3$ .  And my sign my not match yours.

Comment: [Here's the sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28%28-1%29%5E%28n-1%29%2F%28%28%28n%29*%28n%2B1%29%29%2F2%29%29+for+n%3D3+to+infinity) Not sure how to solve analytically. Maybe there's an easy way, maybe there isn't.

Comment: @lulu Yes, a minor tweak is needed. `Sum[(-1)^(n-1)*2/(n(n+1)), {n , 3, infinity}]`

Comment: @peter.petrov  Yeah, I was just illustrating the point.  Not trying to match exactly.

Comment: As a side note, $[1 - (1/2) + (1/3) - (1/4) \cdots]$ $$= ~\left\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\int_0^1 (-1)^k x^k dx\right] \right\}$$ $$= ~\int_0^1 \left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^k\right] ~dx$$ $$= ~\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}dx$$ $$= \log(1+1) - \log(1 + 0).$$

Answer (score 3):

May be worth noting that  my first claim works, if you are a little flexible with summations.  That is to say, that your series can be summed by simple manipulation of the routine expansion $$\ln 2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}n$$

Let $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^{n+1}\times \frac 1{n(n+1)}$$  (again, I am not trying to match your sum exactly, but the differences are minor).  Then use $\frac 1{(n(n+1))}=\frac 1n-\frac 1{n+1}$ to deduce that  $$S=1 - 2\left(\frac 12-\frac 13+\frac 14-\cdots\right)=1+2(\ln 2 -1)=-1+2\ln 2 = -1 +\ln 4$$

You should easily be able to adapt this to your case.

Answer (score 0):

In sigma notation, your series can be written as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=2}^n(-1)^m\frac2{m(m+1)}.$$ Now, here is a hint: $$\sum_{m=2}^n(-1)^m\frac1{m(m+1)}=\sum_{m=2}^n\left[(-1)^m\frac1{m}-(-1)^m\frac1{m+1}\right]=\sum_{m=2}^n\left[(-1)^m\frac1{m}+(-1)^{m+1}\frac1{m+1}\right]=\frac12+2\left[\sum_{m=3}^n(-1)^m\frac1{m}\right]+(-1)^{n+1}\frac1{n+1}.$$ Use this hint.